# Implementing Bable's 'pipeline operator' with Typescript

Tags: typescript, babeljs

I am trying to implement pipeline operator in my Typescript project.
To achieve it I am using babel as my transpiler and Typescript as type checker.

First I tried to run babel with typescript using the following config files:

```
//babel.config.json
 {
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-typescript"],
"plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator", { "proposal": "minimal" }]
  ]
}
```

and

```
//tsconfig.json
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "outDir": "out",

  // Ensure that .d.ts files are created by tsc, but not .js files
  "declaration": true,
  "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
  // Ensure that Babel can safely transpile files in the TypeScript project
  "isolatedModules": true

}
```

}

For basic usage, this implementation worked. To compile it I added to my package.json the following line:

> "scripts": {
> "build": "tsc && babel --extensions ".ts" index.ts -d dist"    }

The problems started when I tried to add pipeline-operator to the project. When I added the operator and tried to compile my project with babel only, using the following command, it worked perfectly:

> babel --extensions ".ts" index.ts -d dist"

but I am not sure how I can use typescript as the type checker, since it doesn't recognize babel's pipeline operator. It is possible to use it in that way?.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is get Babel to transpile **only the pipeline syntax**.
In order to do that, remove the typescript *transform plugin*, and replace it with the typescript [*syntax plugin*](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins#syntax-plugins):

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator", { "proposal": "minimal" }],
  ],
  "parserOpts": {
    "plugins": ["typescript"]
  }
}
```

The output is valid typescript code that can be type-checked.

Comment: Interesting idea! And in order for me to build it I'll need to use both tsc and babel, the I am doing it now?

Comment: I tried to implement it. The typescript checker still doesn't recognize the "|>" syntax. any idea?

Comment: `babel --extensions '.ts' --keep-file-extension src/index.ts -d output/`: this creates a file `output/index.ts` with the pipeline operators removed. It can be typechecked with `tsc output/index.ts`

Comment: Thank you, So you suggest scanning the code, create a new file for each file that contains pipeline-operator using babel parse, and then compiling and type-checking the result with tsc?