# Type checking TypeScript based source maps

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, babeljs

I want to have a compiler going from an extended TypeScript to standard TypeScript, but I want my editor (VS Code) to do type checking based on the standard TypeScript. I can for example use Babel with its pipeline operator plugin `@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator` and have it compile TypeScript using `@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript`. See these [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69116062/implementing-bables-pipeline-operator-with-typescript) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709278/it-is-possible-to-transpile-into-typescript-using-babel#comment133477169_58710486) SO posts. The standard TypeScript produced by Babel works and type checks correctly, but the original file will be full of various errors due to the unsupported use of the pipeline operator.

Is it possible to have TypeScript use the compiled standard TypeScript to typecheck my extended TypeScript file? I can have Babel produce a source map, which is probably necessary to make this work, but I don't know how to go beyond this.

I did find [this open issue for TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13944) to support input source maps.

**Edit**: I wondered how [Civet](https://civet.dev/) made it work, as they certainly have a different syntax than standard TypeScript yet compile to it and have TypeScript check the result. They use a custom language server [that calls the TypeScript language server](https://github.com/DanielXMoore/Civet/blob/main/lsp/source/lib/typescript-service.mts). So I could always fallback on doing something similar if there is no better solution.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin

Comment: Until TypeScript gets a more capable plugin system building a custom LSP extension seems like the only option. It's not too difficult but does require reverse mapping the error locations and forward mapping the hover / ui locations. Hopefully we can expand the Civet LSP to work with any "compiles to TS" language. It already has the concept of plugins for different extensions but needs to standardize on the sourcemap format.